# How to get menu UL to sit next to each other?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Please view what I am looking to do: codepen.io/samiralley/pen/xvFdc

How can I get the nav bar dropdown to show in columns?

Hover over 'Hard Goods' you will see many sections, e.g 'Ashes Caskets' and 'Wood Products'. I want each section to sit next to each other and when it gets to 5 in a row to go onto a new row.

I understand the width would be setting it to 20% which would allow 5 to make the 100%.

For some reason, I can not get it working.

There is a lot of CSS classes so I thought it would be easier to just use Chrome's inspect element?

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Hi Danny, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve although it sounds like it's likely to be possible. Could you show a design or similar somewhere?  If you're trying to display a menu with five items per row, what are you planning on doing when someone's browsing on a smaller screened device?

Comment: Also, part of the issue is that your `.site-nav__item` has an invalid property; you need it to be `width: 20%`, not `width: 20% auto`

Comment: Hello @SonyaBaled I have now taken the auto out of the width. As for what I am looking for, please see this link - https://codepen.io/samiralley/pen/xvFdc Hover over 'About' and the dropdown that appears is what I am looking for, however I would want the dropdown to also be 100% width of the viewport.

Comment: Hey @Allsops, Can you add the code to your question? And remove the link from your question. By making these changes is going to make this question more helpful for anyone in the future. If you change your menu in the future this will make this question unless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked but is quite similar. This shows a number of menu based on available space (height and width) with an overflow. Try to replace the following class in this way (be sure that all the rules will be applied, add `!important` if necessary). Maybe is not what you desire but could be a starting point.

```
.site-nav--has-grandchildren {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: end;
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width: unset;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Fabio ! Works perfectly :)